# Is it possible to add an a tooltip for each item that shows up in the autocomplete using c#?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Is it possible to add an a tooltip for each item that shows up in the autocomplete using c# ?

Give complete answer in only c# please

Comment: "The autocomplete"? I think a little more information is needed.

Comment: In what autocomplete? Could give a little more context about what your are doing?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean IntelliSense while you're coding? If so, you need to provide [XML doucmentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something to the object.
/// </summary>
public void Foo()
{
    // Code here
}
```

If you type /// above your method declaration, Visual Studio will provide a template.